# Getting Error: "All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provide" in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't seem to get rid of this error. I'am using create-react-app with TypeScript. Any help, appreciated. Thanks.

```
All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.  TS1208

  > 1 | import randomcolor from 'randomcolor';
      | ^
    2 | import React from 'react';
    3 | import tasksData from '../../assets/data/tasksData';
    4 | import { Task } from '../../model/task';
```

These are my tsconfig files. I created a base file as the original tsconfig file gets overwritten by the react build scripts.

tsconfig.base.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "isolatedModules": false
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

Comment: I have no idea, but I searched the web and found https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6054, which pointed me to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21194, so: are you following correct typescript rules in the `randomcolor` code?

Comment: Please do NOT use images for code.  Post the actual code. We need to see it

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Noted, thanks.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans randomcolor is a npm package. I suspect it is not following the correct rules however would like to stop this error propagating to the build. https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomcolor

Comment: maybe randomcolor component has a repeated name or links inside,or you have a another with the same name component

Answer (score 33):

May get this error with an unused `.ts`or `.tsx` file. I had empty `.ts` file I wasn't using so just had to delete the unused file.

deleted the unused file `/example/index.ts`

Comment: This is what caught me out, I was getting ahead of myself and creating the files in a folder first before writing any code in them. This is what got me over the error.

Answer (score 26):

The problem is that in Typescript by default, every file without `import`or `export` is a legacy scrip file.

As such files are not modules they are merged in the global namespace.

**To change this behavior**

a) add any **import** or **export** in the file, eg: `export {}`

b) set `"isolatedModules": false` in tsconfig.json

**Note**: NextJS will reset the value to `true` in every build, because for NextJS, `"isolatedModules": true` is a requirement

Comment: The empty export solved my problem. However surprisingly the setting of isolatedModules to true doesn't helped.

Comment: @webpreneur because you should set it to "false"

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error too. The reason why this is happening is that the react component you have created is not being used. So you can call the component, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

there is no export in the file!

for example you can add `export default {}` to fixed!

Comment: The information provided is not enough. Please provide more information so that we can assist you.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting any unused .tsx file should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that anything you are importing is being exported from that path.

If it specific to the `randomcolor` import, make sure you also add the types for that package by installing `@types/randomcolor`

**npm**

```
npm i @types/randomcolor
```

**yarn**

```
yarn add @types/randomcolor
```

Comment: Thanks, however I have the types installed.

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting isolatedModules to true in your tsconfig.json then to false in  your base? Any reason you have to extend that setting?

Comment: The react scripts overwrite the tsconfig file at build time. I created a base file thinking I might be able to switch off isolatedModules but no luck

Comment: For me, it was lacking an export for a function in a file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had a file in which I had import and export statements. The issue was that file was never used. As soon as I imported something from that file, this error was gone.
So, if you are making a file like a common button and you saved that file, make sure you used that button before looking at the output.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. But seeing a solution mentioned above **typescript requires import/export**. I added only this line

```
import bgps from '../../resources/bgps.png';
```

Then the error gone. so even if it's a file that requires no import then keep one unused image file. though it'll cause warning in console log

in the following day I also got same error! Closed VS Code, opened again and bang! it was okay again

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when I created a `.ts` file instead of `.tsx`. I got the error after deleting the errant `.ts` file. Restarting my dev server resloved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code i have. TDLR, u can try to `module.exports = {}` at the bottom of the page.

```
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
})

const question = (question) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question(question, (answer) => {
      resolve(answer)
    })
  })
}

const main = async () => {
  const username = await question('Please enter a username: ');
  const password = await question('Please enter a password: ');
  const email = await question('Please enter an email:');
  console.log("result: ", {
      "username" : username,
      "password" : password
  });
  rl.close()
}

main()

module.exports = {}
```

I tried to use `export {}` but it did not work for me partly because i was trying to execute this file using node. so if u are executing the file using node, then use `module.exports` as shown above.

i would prefer to use set `"isolatedModules": false` in tsconfig.json
but because i need to run this separately alongside a next.js project
this approach have worked for me.

the command to run to execute the file

```
node file_name_here.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

for me closing the unused file tab from vs code workspace resolved the problem.. also deleting unused files helps sometimes too.

or sometimes just saving the files (ctrl+s) works fine for me. sometimes a page refresh is needed.

Answer (score 0):

this happen to me all the times. just saving the files (ctrl+s) works fine for me. sometimes a page refresh is needed.